# How can I add a custom validation message for banned users in this Laravel 8 application?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a **blogging application in Laravel 8**.

There are *4 user roles*, among which, the "Super-admin". The super admin can **ban all users that are not Super-admins**.

[image]

The banning happens as follows:

In the `users` table, there is an `active` column of type *tinyint*.

In the **UserRightsController** controller I have this small function that does the banning:

```
public function ban_user($id){
      User::find($id)->update(['active' => 0]);
      return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'The user is now banned');
}
```

Once a user is banned, she/he will be *unable to login*. I have achieved this by going to `vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\AuthenticatesUsers.php` and changing this:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}

to

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['active' => 1]);
}
```

#### The problem:

Any attempt by a banned user to sign in fails, but the error message is still the default one:

> These credentials do not match our records.

[image]

The login form (view):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
  @csrf

  <div class="row mb-2">
      <label for="email" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Email Address') }}</label>

      <div class="col-md-12 @error('email') has-error @enderror">
          <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" autocomplete="email" autofocus>

          @error('email')
              <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                  <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
              </span>
          @enderror
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mb-2">
      <label for="password" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

      <div class="col-md-12 @error('password') has-error @enderror">
          <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" autocomplete="current-password">

          @error('password')
              <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                  <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
              </span>
          @enderror
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

              <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                  {{ __('Remember Me') }}
              </label>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mb-0">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-primary">
              {{ __('Login') }}
          </button>

          @if (Route::has('password.request'))
              <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                  {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
              </a>
          @endif
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### EDIT:

In `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`, I have overwritten the `credentials` from AuthenticatesUsers.php:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
 {
   return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['active' => 1]);
 }
```

But the issue of a specific message remains :(

#### Questions:

1. How do I add a custom message like: "Your account was suspended"?
2. Is there a better alternative to using `return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['active' => 1])` in AuthenticatesUsers.php?

Comment: You should be able to overwrite the `sendFailedLoginResponse()` and probably also overwrite the `login()` function...

Comment: Wow, you really change code in vedor? Btw, use middleware to check active status and redirect with message if user is banned

Comment: @Maksim One of the questions is if there is a better alternative to changing the code in the vendor directory, the way I did. You can provide an alternative in your answer, :)

Comment: Yes, as i said - use middleware - you can read about this here.  Or make custom auth guard, but this is overenginering. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware

Comment: The normal way to do this is either create a middleware or to overwrite the logic of your LoginController. This controller uses the AuthenticatesUsers Trait.
You should never overwrite code in your vendor folder directly...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working, although not perfect, solution:

In `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`, I have overwritten the `authenticated` method, instead of the `credentials` method:

```
protected function authenticated()
{
  if (Auth::user()->active !== 1) {
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/login')->withError('Your account is not active!');
  }
}
```

In the login view, above the form:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
    <p class="my-0 text-center">{{ session('error') }}</p>
</div>
```

[image]